# Remove any apostrophes from string - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Could someone help!py I am only trying to remove any apostrophes from string text in my data frame, I am not sure what am missing.

I have regular express and replace and renaming but can't seem to get rid of it.

```
country                           designation  points  price  \
0      US                     Martha's Vineyard    96.0  235.0   
1   Spain  Carodorum Selección Especial Reserva    96.0  110.0   
2      US         Special Selected Late Harvest    96.0   90.0   
3      US                               Reserve    96.0   65.0   
4  France                            La Brûlade    95.0   66.0   

         province           region_1           region_2             variety  \
0      California        Napa Valley               Napa  Cabernet Sauvignon   
1  Northern Spain               Toro                NaN       Tinta de Toro   
2      California     Knights Valley             Sonoma     Sauvignon Blanc   
3          Oregon  Willamette Valley  Willamette Valley          Pinot Noir   
4        Provence             Bandol                NaN  Provence red blend   

                    winery  last_year_points  
0                    Heitz                94  
1  Bodega Carmen Rodríguez                92  
2                 Macauley
```

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace("''","")
df.Designation=df.Designation.str.replace("''","")
import re
re.sub("\'+",'',df.Designation)
df.rename(Destination={'Martha's Vineyard:'Mathas'}, inplace=True)
```

```
Error Message:SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are doing `replace("''","")` so you will only replace *pairs* of apostrophes that occur together. Did you mean to do `replace("'","")`?

Answer (score 1):

See the code snippet below to solve your problem using a combination of lambda inline functions and the replace function for a string object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["Tom's", "Jerry's", "Harry"]})
print(df, '\n')
```

> Tom's Jerry's Harry

```
# Remove any apostrophes using lambda and replace function
df = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'", ""))
print(df, '\n')
```

> Toms Jerrys Harry

Comment: Thank you loads, you saved my morning.

Comment: Cheers mate!
If it solved your problem, kindly upvote and mark it as a solution.